# Can't find user by email address from params. Works without params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, parameters

So I have a basic controller where I want to find a user and return json.

This works fine

`User.find_by(email: "foo@bar.com") => #<User>`

This does NOT work

`User.find_by(email: params[:email]) => nil`

Route is setup as such

`get 'foo/:email' => 'foo#bar'`

When I log the value of params I can clearly see email is assigned and has a value.

I also have devise installed for my user auth so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

And help is much appreciated, I can not figure this one out.

**Edit 1**

Just figured it out. my route params /:email when just passing it is at route/foo@bar.com the param was only picking up "foo@bar" and not the .com

Fixed this by using ?email= instead.

Comment: Show your Rails console log...

Comment: test puts "***************#params[:email]" on your console, make sure email is present in params.

Comment: Looking at the log more closely helped, I was skimming over the .com bit of the email.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't send email in your route. Rather you can send id. Because query string doesn't support special character.

If you don't have any other option to send id then create a base64 string with your email and send it in query string.

Comment: This was almost it, it was sending "foo@bar" instead of the full "foo@bar.com" I ended up having to do ?email= style params

Comment: As I said that query string doesn't support special character, so If you don't have any other option to send id then create a base64 string with your email and send it in query string.

Comment: Not true, you can send an email address (dots and all) in a route just fine if you configure the route appropriately to get around the automatic format detection.